# VBA Autofilter Excel 2013?

Tags: vba, excel, autofilter, office-2013

I've been using a line like:

```
Cells.AutoFilter 11, "0"
```

for a while to autofilter column 11 for "0".

I recently updated to Microsoft Office 2013 and now I'm getting an `AutoFilter method of Range class failed` runtime error with this line.  Is this a compatibility issue with Office 2013 or some other problem?

EDIT:  I should clarify that I am not getting an error with a program I already run, but rather a line which I've used before and is not working for me right now.

EDIT2: [image: Spreadsheet I'm working on]

Code:

```
Dim firstRow As Integer
Dim lastRow As Integer
Dim firstCol As Integer
Dim lastCol As Integer
Dim allRange As Range
Dim vRange As Range
Dim bRange As Range
Dim commentsCol As Integer
Dim commentsColRng As Range
Dim fieldNameCol As Integer
Dim userCol As Integer

If Cells(2, 1) <> "" Then

    firstCol = 1
    lastCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    firstRow = 2
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    commentsCol = Rows(1).find("Comments").Column '11
    fieldNameCol = Rows(1).find("Field Name").Column '8
    userCol = Rows(1).find("User").Column '4

    Set allRange = Range(Cells(firstRow, firstCol), Cells(lastRow, lastCol))
    Set commentsColRng = Range(Cells(firstRow, commentsCol), Cells(lastRow, commentsCol))

    Cells.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="PF"
    Cells.AutoFilter commentsCol, "0", xlFilterValues
    Cells.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="0", Operator:=xlFilterValues

End If
```

I have three autofilters because I'm trying it multiple different ways.

Comment: Hmm, that is strange. Does the `Same` file with `Same` Code work in Excel 2010?

Comment: As an FYI, I just pulled up a copy of Excel 2013 and used code such as yours to test and it worked fine. Are you sure it isn't an issue where the code is running on the `Activesheet` (implicitly since the code doesn't specify a sheet), and you actually need to be filtering a different sheet? Are you sure column 11 has data?

Comment: @SiddharthRout I believe we were originally on Office 2003, so I wouldn't know about 2010.  And a similar line still works from a program which I wrote previously. `Cells.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="0", Operator:=xlFilterValues`

Comment: @user3561813  I'll try specifying a sheet but I know column 11 has data

Answer (score 0):

You might not have anything in column 11.

For example:

```
     A         B
---------------------
1  field1   field2
2  a             0 
3  b             1
4  c             2
5  d            23

Sub Test()
    ' this will succeed because column 2 (B) has something
    Cells.AutoFilter 2, "0"

    ' this will fail because column 3 (C) has nothing to filter on
    ' error message will be AutoFilter method of Range class failed
    Cells.AutoFilter 3, "0"
End Sub
```

Comment: I know all of column 11 has data.  The line `Cells.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="0", Operator:=xlFilterValues` from a previous macro works fine for its program, yet the line `Cells.AutoFilter 11, "0", xlFilterValues` for this one does not.

Comment: Can you upload the Excel sheet somewhere? If we take a look at that, we might be able to help better.

Comment: Updated the original post

Comment: I created the same dataset from the screenshot and ran the code you have with zero problems. The code worked just fine.

Comment: And you're using Excel 2013?

Comment: Hey I created a follow up question.  Look at it if you feel up to it?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31747522/vba-different-requirements-when-coding  Thank you