# VBA: Different requirements when coding

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013, autofilter

This is a follow up question from [a previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31730259/vba-autofilter-excel-2013).

So the company I work for has recently updated their Excel from 2003 to 2013.  I am now having issues with some pretty basic VBA code.  The line `Cells.AutoFilter(x, y)` in particular is giving me issues.

---

I wrote a very ugly program months ago which looks something like this:

```
...
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:= _
    "0"
If wf.CountA(r) > 0 Then
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:= _
    Array("baseunitprice", "burden", "MTLBURRATE", "PurPoint", "Vendornum"), Operator _
    :=xlFilterValues
Range("K2:K50000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "MACROUSE"
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.FillDown
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=8
...
```

This is the first program I wrote and must be rewritten for obvious reasons.

---

In an attempt to mirror the above code in a more elegant, readable way, I created another Sub in the same module:

```
Sub ActualProgram()

Dim firstRow As Integer
Dim lastRow As Integer
Dim firstCol As Integer
Dim lastCol As Integer
Dim allRange As Range
Dim vRange As Range
Dim bRange As Range
Dim commentsCol As Integer
Dim commentsColRng As Range
Dim fieldNameCol As Integer
Dim userCol As Integer

If Cells(2, 1) <> "" Then

    DeleteEmptyRows

    firstCol = 1
    lastCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    firstRow = 2
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    commentsCol = Rows(1).find("Comments").Column '11
    fieldNameCol = Rows(1).find("Field Name").Column '8
    userCol = Rows(1).find("User").Column '4

    Set allRange = Range(Cells(firstRow, firstCol), Cells(lastRow, lastCol))
    Set commentsColRng = Range(Cells(firstRow, commentsCol), Cells(lastRow, commentsCol))

    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter 11, "0"     'WORKS
    Cells.AutoFilter commentsCol, "0"                              'FAILS

    Call MarkFieldNames(fieldNameCol, commentsColRng)

    Call MarkNonSMFields(commentsColRng)

    Call TargetFieldNames(fieldNameCol, commentsCol)

End If

End Sub
```

This sub is never called in the previous program, of course.  I just wanted to have both codes together so I could refer to the previous one while writing the new one.

The line I'm having issues with in the new code is 
`Cells.AutoFilter commentsCol, "0"`.

The line which I used in the old code is `ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:="0"`

The old code still works fine.  The new one throws an `AutoFilter method of Range class failed` run-time error.  In my eyes, these two lines do the exact same thing, and I've used the line `Cells.AutoFilter(x, y)` too many times to count without error on Excel 2013.

---

Is there a setting I need to change?  I ask because I see in **VBA > Tools > Options > Editor** there are **Code Settings** options such as `Require Variable Declaration`, which leads me to belive that there may be a setting which disables the way I call the `AutoFilter()` method.

---

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Oh wow.  This is a table.  It's not just data in cells, it's a table with data inside it.  Is that my error?

Comment: In your activesheet, you do have an object named "Table1", correct? Silly question but perhaps it's called something else in the new workbook?

Comment: Well that must be the case.  I kept looking at this table like it was just regular cells, but this must be a table in the template which I'm writing for.  Now that I know it's "Table1", is there a better way I can write the line `ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter 11, "0"`?

Answer (score 0):

I am working with a table.  Hence `ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1")...`  Tables are treated differently than regular cells, and therefore, must be specifically targeted when autofiltering.